# How to fix spinnaker installation error "Failed to deploy Spinnaker." (spinnaker v2 mode installation)?

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I am trying to install spinnaker on my kubernetes cluster but while it was being installed it failed to create namespace on my cluster getting error.

> ERROR Unexpected exception:
>   io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: >[list]  for
>   kind: [Pod]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [spinnaker]  failed.
>   - Failed to deploy Spinnaker.

Follow deployment process written on spinnaker [official documentation](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/).

Checked rbac policy for kubernetes, but I have full accesson my cluster

Comment: Have you gone through this https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/4290

Comment: No, thanks for sharing, let me check